# How can I design User Preferences module in my Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, architecture, preferences

I have dialog for storing user preferences of the application which is developed using Java Swing. There are 20+ preferences and I would like to notify other modules when the particular preference changes. I know that I can hold a list of listeners and notify them whenever the preferences change. However, I would like to know about two issues:

- How can I bind my Swing components to a bean object,
- How can I fire an event when the preferences change,

Dependending your experience, how would you resolve that architecture? What are the best practices to follow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I developed a Swing application where the user could modify some parameters to change functionality or the graphic of the application.

I approached it this way:

- A general `Setting` abstract class represent a single value that the user can change.
- A subclass is created for different types of value, in my case: boolean, integer, floating points, colors, etc.
- I use a Map to keep track of the created `Setting` and a `Preferences` object to store the values.

For the actual settings, I create a static attribute somewhere (in my case, dedicated classes for different logical groups of settings) and use that attribute to read and change the values fo the settings.

PRO: The `Settings` keeps track of all the settings instantiated, so I don't need to code the frame for changing them twice, I just did it once in an indipendent way from the number of the settings

CONS: It clearly requires changing the code to add a new setting. While in my case it was not an issue because a new setting was needed only because of other changes in the code, in your case it might be.

Comment: How do you let other objects know about changes/updates in any of the Settings? Thanks.

Comment: I kept it simple, the code that needs the setting doesn't store the value but always use the static variable, getting the most updated value. You could add a map of listeners, but I'm quite sure there are better ways